# crop image in react-native in background

Tags: react-native, ocr, image-editing, react-native-vision-camera

I am using react-native-vision-camer to took picture of some text, and later I provide it (uri to cached image) to @react-native-ml-kit/text-recognition (OCR lib for text-recognition).

It occurs that I only need central part of image (like 30% of image field) so I thought about cutting part of it and only providing new, edited image, but am stuck with finding working tool for it. Best would be to edit image (cut by pixels), save it in cache and provide to OCR uri for cache.

I tried [react-native ImageEditor](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.60/imageeditor) (depreciated) and corresponding community libraries, but all are depreciated or need license. Also tried react-native-image-resizer but it only help with changing size or ratio, but not with cutting image

I also do not need any crop-components, I have to do it in background, to get smaller image (without loosing resolution) for app performance